# Show BASE64 video with node/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, video, base64

So, bit of an odd problem. I have a bunch of media files saved as base64 strings in mongo, some are images, some are videos.

I made an API for getting the media files:

```
app.get('/api/media/:media_id', function (req, res) {
    media.findById(req.params.media_id)
        .exec(function (err, media) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            var file = new Buffer(media.file, 'base64');
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': media.type, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'BASE64', 'Content-Length': file.length});
            res.end(file);
        });
});
```

Now, images have no problems. They load just fine, both directly from the API, and when I call the API from a front-end (for example `<img src="/api/media/23498423">`)

THE PROBLEM

If I fetch a video from a front-end, like the images - but with a video- or object-tag:

```
<video src="/api/media/3424525" controls></video>
```

there's no problem, but if I load the video in a browser directly from the API:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/media/3424525
```

the server process crashes, no errors. It simply just freezes up. And we're not talking about huge video files - it's a 1.5MB video.

The media type in the header for all the videos I'm testing with is `video/mp4`. Oh, and just to be clear: if I do the same with images, everything works perfectly.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so as suggested by @idbehold and @zeeshan I took a look at gridfs and gridfs-stream, and for the purpose of my app, this certainly is what I should have used in the first place. However, after implementing gridfs in my app, the problem still persists.

```
app.get('/api/media/:media_id', function (req, res) {
    gfs.findOne({ _id: req.params.media_id }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        if (!file) {
            return res.status(404).send('');
        }

        res.set('Content-Type', file.contentType);
        res.set('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' + file.filename + '"');

        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            _id: file._id
        });

        readstream.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Got an error while processing stream: ", err.message);
            res.end();
        });

        readstream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

When I call the media file (be it image or video) from a front-end, within a HTML tag, everything works out fine. But if I load a video (again, smallish videos from 1.5mb to max 6mb total size) directly in the browser, the server process freezes. To be a bit more clear: I am testing on windows, and the server app (server.js) is run in console. The console and the process it is running is what freezes. I cannot load any more pages/views in the node app, and I cannot even stop/kill/shutdown the node app or the console.

Comment: For a 1.5MB video file you're now going to have 3MB in memory at the time you call `res.end(file)`. You should be streaming the video straight to `res` without buffering. You should be using something like Mongo's GridFS and its streaming API. You'll probably have to add support for byte-range requests as well.

Comment: I didn't know gridfs, I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the [GridStore API](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/gridfs.md) is what you'll want to use.

Comment: I disagree that you want GridFS if the files are indeed small. But the real question is why use base64 encoding? GridFS driver features are just going to break up in chunks and store as `BinData` anyway. Which of course you can just directly store and return the binary data in any collection property ( all GridFS is doing anyway ). So I would personally just store as binary then create a handle and `.pipe()` to `res`.

Comment: I see your points. The answer is a number of reasons. 1. I didn't know you could store binary data in mongo. 2. I might need to store bigger files in the future, but I was unaware of the 16mb document limit.

Comment: @BrianEmilius did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 8):

Streaming videos directly to/from GridFS using [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) either with *mongodb-native db instance* or *mongoose*.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Grid = require('gridfs-stream'),
    db = new mongo.Db('yourDatabaseName', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017)),
    gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

//store
app.post('/video', function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: 'file_name_here'
    }));
    res.send("Success!");
});

//get
app.get('/video/:vid', function (req, res) {
    gfs.createReadStream({
        _id: req.params.vid // or provide filename: 'file_name_here'
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

*for complete files and running project:*

Clone node-cheat [direct_upload_gridfs](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/gridfs/direct_upload_gridfs), run `node app` followed by `npm install express mongodb gridfs-stream`.

Answer (score 4):

Truly an odd problem...
I could be way off, but it's worth a shot:

One of the differences when opening a url directly from the browser is that the browser will also try to fetch `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico` (while trying to find the tab icon). Maybe the problem is not related to your video code, but rather to some other route, trying to handle the `/favicon.ico` request?

Have you tried using `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: This is worth looking into. Good call.

Comment: I did some extensive testing and in none of the instances where the application process crashed were there any problems fetching favicon.ico - it was a good suggestion though, so +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, maybe this is a dumb suggestion, but what is the browser you are using? Maybe something from Microsoft causes the problem...

Comment: I test in chrome, firefox, firefox dev, opera, ie9+10, and edge with the same result, also on android chrome